# Can blocks completely replace delegates?Yes or No

Tags: ios, delegates, nsnotifications

1. Intially NSUrlConnection Class having 3 delegates  methods but later they will changed it to blocks for example [NSUrlConnection sendAsynchronusRequest]
2. Why apple uses UITableview delegates method for this.Can be replace delegate methods with blocks.If yes / no? Please explain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objective-c delegation to multiple objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278857/objective-c-delegation-to-multiple-objects)

Comment: Your question title and question text ask different things. The title asks whether blocks can replace delegates but your text is asking about multiple delegates

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can make a delegate chain to do this.For example A->B->C...B is A's delegate,C is B's.B can call its delegate function when A call its delegate function.And they can follow the same delegate or not.